# How to do the project painting in Krita

Tags: color, texture, painting, krita

I would like to know if I can use Krita to make the projection painting of a picture over an UV layout previously exported from blender (2.8). Below you can see how it is the UV layout of the eyebrow of my character :

[image: eyebrows UV layout]

and this is the picture that I want to use to "color" the UV layout :

[image: eyebrows picture]

Essentially I want to spread the picture inside the UV layout contours,in the same way it is done in the projection painting tecnique like [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMSdna1Fi2A&t=6s)

This is what I want to do : I want to spread/adapt/color the picture exactly as is inside the UV layout,(**but I don't want to pick the color inside the picture of the eyebrows !)**

[image: picture over the UV layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to deform the existing eyebrow image so that it fits inside your other image that you call UV layout.

Put one eyebrow to another layer of the same image as your UV layout. Scale and rotate the eyebrow as near as possible with the Transform tool:

[image]

Use Cage Transformation or Warping (=submodes of the Transform tool) to stretch and bend the eyebrow to its final form; like this:

[image]

Close temporarily the eyebrow layer, select with the Magic Wand the emptiness around your UV layout image and use that selection to delete the stray parts in the eyebrow layer:

[image]

Unfortunately I haven't Blender nor know how it works, so I have no idea how to place this image to your model. But at least it fits inside the UV layout image.

Comment: is there another way to do this ? For example if I have UV layouts with a more complicated shape and the texture is hard to deform to fit inside the space,what's the solution then ?

Comment: Your linked video copied (=projected) stuff from a image (a scalped and straightened skin) onto surface. You can do the same and copy stuff from the 2D texture image directly onto the 3D surface. If there's material borders, be sure there's also a 3D subshape border and close that part which needs another texture. Another way is to create the texture image to it's needed form. If the texture has lines which should continue over a surface border, some real trickery is needed. I'm not a master of it, sorry. I guess that some markers must be placed in 3D.

Comment: @Marietto (continued) Many 2D programs have well working image brushes, at least Illustrator and Affinity Designer have it. Learn to make seamlessly continuing fill patterns. That's another needed skill. I guess both of these are useful when one wants to create texture images.